# Different versions of 'diff' giving mixed results when comparing 2 identical files

Tags: php, html, diff

I have 2 HTML files which I believe are identical, but certain versions of `diff` are giving conflicting results.

The 2 files have been downloaded from a remote URL using PHP curl (http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). The files were downloaded on different days, but I believe the content has not changed, including any of the markup. The purpose of the application is actually to determine whether there were changes or not.

The file sizes are identical; both 358,341 bytes. A visual inspection of the content shows them to be identical.

To make sure there are no differences in the markup or other contents I've used [DiffMerge](https://sourcegear.com/diffmerge/) on my local machine and it's reporting that the files are identical.

However, when I ssh into a centOS server and do a comparison, it's showing the following from running `diff file1.html file2.html`

```
    12159,12161c12159,12161
    <   
    < 
    < 
    ---
    >   
    > 
    > 
    12163,12172c12163,12172
    < 
    < 
    < 
    < 
    < 
    < 
    < 
    < 
    < 
    < 
    ---
    > 
    > 
    > 
    > 
    > 
    > 
    > 
    > 
    > 
    > 
    12174c12174
    < 
    ---
    >
```

When I look at those line numbers in a text editor there are no noticeable differences. What does this output actually mean?

I've also used a web-based diff tool, https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-diff, which is reporting exactly the same line numbers as being different. However the output when viewed in "side by side" mode (`file1.html` vs `file2.html`) is exactly the same!

Does anyone have any ideas how to debug this or what the issue may be? The files were downloaded using the same script and method in both instances and, as far as I know, there's no encoding differences.

Comment: Are there any white-spaces (tab/new line/blanks) differences?

Comment: Did you now about controll characters like line-breaks, indent and other stuff. The content of a file is more that you can see, most of the time. Get something like notepad+ and check the content with this.

Comment: Thank you both. The tabs/spaces are identical on the affected line numbers. I've used Sublime to check this and even highlighted over the area to "see" what the tabs/spaces look like; they are the same on both files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
diff -w file1.html file2.html
```

From the manual:

```
-w  --ignore-all-space  Ignore all white space.
```

White space characters include tab, vertical tab, form feed, carriage return, and space; some locales may define additional characters to be white space. [source](http://gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/White-Space.html)

Comment: This is very interesting because when I run it, no differences are shown. So does this mean the strange output I was getting is due to spacing? I looked at the tabs/spacing in an editor, as per someone else's advice, and there are no visual differences, so I don't understand how this is possible?

Comment: White space characters include tab, vertical tab, form feed, carriage return, and space; some locales may define additional characters to be white space.
Source: https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/White-Space.html

Answer (score 0):

Use a hexeditor to diff the two files, i am pretty sure that they are not identical. You will see the difference. For example wxHexEditor is free, multiplatform and is able to diff.

Comment: I've tried wxHexEditor just now and it's showing nothing in the Comparison panel when comparing the 2 files. It's really weird, but I guess `diff` on my centOS server is seeing some difference - see the accepted answer.

Comment: Weird. From what you wrote it seems like there is a local version and a remote version. Maybe it altered during upload like it can e.g. using ftp text mode. If you run a checksum (sha256sum filename) do they output the same?

Comment: Yes, this is a very good point - there *is* a local and remote copy. The local one was being compared using software on my local machine (DiffMerge, wxHexEditor) and the remotes being compared on a centOS server using `diff`, and also a PHP diff tool mentioned in my original post. The strange thing is these files were downloaded *on the remote server* which is where it's showing them to be different; on my local machine they are identical which is really the opposite of what you might expect since the transfer was remote to local, not the other way. Ignoring whitespace remotely fixes it though